# Delphi: Can't Draw On Panel's Canvas

Tags: image, delphi, canvas, draw

I'm trying to draw an image on a TPanel's Canvas in a procedure of this Panel. When I do this in Paint Method of the Panel it works just fine, but when I try to draw on the Canvas in another procedure or in the constructor nothing happens.

This is how I draw on the Panel's Canvas in the Paint Procedure:

```
procedure TFeld.Paint;
var bmp : TBitmap;
begin
  inherited;
  bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    bmp.LoadFromFile('textures\ground.bmp');
    self.Canvas.Draw(0,0,bmp);
  finally
    bmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

And this is how I try to draw on it in another procedure:

```
procedure TFeld.setUnsichtbar;
var bmp : TBitmap;
begin
  bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    bmp.LoadFromFile('textures\invisible.bmp');
    self.Canvas.Draw(0,0,bmp);
  finally
    bmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

But the Panel's Canvas is still the image I applied in the Paint procedure.

I already tried to move the drawing from the Paint procedure to the Constructor which didn't work.

The path is also correct, switched the paths and now the Panels have the 'invisible.bmp' image.

Whole Class/Unit: http://pastebin.com/YhhDr1F9

Any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: Because all drawing needs to be done in `OnPaint`, and trying to do so elsewhere will not work because when the `Paint` event occurs it will undo everything you've done elsewhere when the window or panel is painted. This is the equivalent of *"Doctor, it hurts when I do this." and the doctor replying "So stop doing that."*. It doesn't work when you draw somewhere other than `OnPaint`, and the solution is *stop drawing somewhere other than `OnPaint`*.

Comment: I'd start with Petzold's book and understand InvalidateRect and WM_PAINT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your whole class I asume you desire to controll which image is being shown at which time based on certain condition. Right?

If that is the case first thing that you need is for your class to have a field for storing the image data. In your example above you are only using bmp files so TBitmap would suffice. But if you are using other picture types you might want to use TPicture field instead as this one alows loading of all supported picture images as TImage that you also tried to use component can.

Then you change your component's Paint method to use the above mentioned field for getting picture data instead of creating local picture data variable every time as you do it now.
In fact what you are doing now is terrible as you are forcing your application to read the image data from file into memory every time your component is rendered. This could cause terrible performance.

And finally when you want to change the picture that is shown on your component just load different picture into your picture field.

So with above changes your class should look something like this:

```
type 
  TFeld=class(TPanel)
  protected
    procedure Paint;override;
    procedure BitmapChange(Sender: TObject);
  private
    zSichtbar : Boolean;
    zPosHor,zPosVer : Integer; // Position im Array
    zEinheit  : TEinheit;
    Bitmap: TBitmap; //Field for storing picture data
  public

//    hImage    : TImage;

    constructor Create(pX,pPosHor,pY,pPosVer,pHoehe,pBreite:integer;pImgPath:String;pForm:Tform); virtual;
    destructor Destroy;
    procedure ChangeImage(pImgPath: String);
  end;

...

implementation

constructor TFeld.Create(pX,pPosHor,pY,pPosVer,pHoehe,pBreite:integer;pImgPath:String;pForm:Tform);
begin
  inherited create(pForm);

  ...

  //Creater internal component for storing image data
  Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  //Assign proper method to Bitmaps OnChange event
  Bitmap.OnChange := BitmapChange;
  //Load initial image data
  Bitmap.LoadFromFile(pImgPath);

  ....

end;

destructor Destroy;
begin
  //We need to destroy the internal component for storing image data before 
  //we destory our own component in order to avoid memory leaks
  Bitmap.Free;
end;

procedure TFeld.Paint;
begin
  inherited;
  //Use local image field to tell the Paint method of what to render
  self.Canvas.Draw(0,0,Bitmap);
end;

procedure TFeld.BitmapChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //Force redrawing of the component on bitmap change
  self.Invalidate;
end;

procedure TFeld.ChangeImage(pImgPath: String);
begin
  //Load different image into image field
  Bitmap.LoadFromFile(pImgPath);
end;
```

EDIT: Adding necessary code to force component redrawing after bitmap has been changed.

Comment: Your `ChangeImage` method should include `Self.Invalidate` after changing the image, so that `Paint` is called to reflect the change.

Comment: The correct approach is to assign an event handler to the `TBitmap.OnChange` event and have it call `Invalidate()`.  This accounts for **any** changes to the bitmap.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You are also correct. I have edited my answer acordingly

Comment: @KenWhite You are correct. I completly forgot about that. It is clear that I'm more used to working with game engines where such thing isn't necessary since the whole sceene is invalidated every time.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved the problem perfectly and everything works properly now. Thanks again! :)